# @PropertyName not working properly when there is a space in field name

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have one field called "Serial Number" in firebase database, i want to show its value to android application. I have user @PropertyName annotation to access it through model class.

```
@PropertyName("Serial Number")
private String serialNumber;
```

But it is not working, if i remove space from firebase database as well as from model class, it works fine. But how to do it with space in field name?

Comment: Have you try to replace SPACE with _ "underscore" ? I think using _ "underscore" is more convenient rather than SPACE.

Comment: @HareshChhelana Sorry, didn't get what you are trying to say

Comment: try to use public instead of private in serialNumber

Comment: @MohitSuthar Great, that worked. But then why other fields are working even with `private` modifier?

Comment: If you wan to define any field as private than declare @PropertyName to getter and setter and remove from field declaration.

Answer (score 3):

Along with declaring variable name as @PropertyName, you need to add @PropertyName for getter and setter as below:

```
@PropertyName("Serial Number")
private String serialNumber;

@PropertyName("Serial Number")
public String getSerialNumber() {
     return serialNumber;
}

@PropertyName("Serial Number")
public void setSerialNumber(String serialNumber) {
     this.serialNumber = serialNumber;
}
```